# Использование поля абстрактного класса

Tags: java

Есть абстрактный класс с полем `protected String[] arrWords;`, если в классе-наследнике инициализирую `arrWords` внутри конструктора, то все работает нормально, но не могу инициализировать вне конструктора.

```
public class NegativeTextAnalyzer extends KeywordAnalyzer {

    String[] stop = new String[] {":(", "=(", ":|"};

    arrWords = stop;

    @Override
    protected String[] getKeywords() {
        return new String[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected Label getLabel(String[] keys, String text) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: а как это делаете? Покажите код пжлст. Ошибку выдаёт какую-либо?

Comment: "не могу инициализировать вне конструктора, почему так" - нипочему. Можете.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, поправил вопрос

Comment: @GlebKamisaraw Минус тогда ставлю Вам.

Comment: @Igor, за что? Unknown class: 'arrWords' вот такая ошибка, если внутри конструктора такой проблемы нет

Comment: Вы снаружи Вашего класса это пишете?

Comment: @Igor, нет, внутри класса-наследника

Comment: То есть код Вы показывать не хотите? Вы партизан?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заверните этот код в фигурные скобки.

[Initialization Block](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/instance-initialization-block-iib-java/#:%7E:text=Initialization%20blocks%20are%20executed%20whenever,include%20them%20in%20your%20classes.)

Comment: Только разбираюсь в java и не знал, что нужно так делать, спасибо!